# app.get('/') not being called when site opened

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I open my site (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8090), a GET request to / is not made.

```
app.use(session({
  //session stuff
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('client'));

app.get('/', async function(req, res){
  console.log(req);
}

module.exports = app;
app.listen(8090);
```

This is not being called and I am unsure why - what can I do to fix this? My other app.get() functions are called when the relevant pages are opened.

Comment: Is your file compiled/interpreted properly? I see a syntax error. Close app.get route with ')' and try. Its workingfine for me.

Comment: I closed it with ) and still seem to have the same problem. When I call app.get('*', ...) instead of this, I seem to get an output when I open the page

Comment: @Sreehari the only way I can get app.get('/') to be called is if I put it before `app.use(express.static('client'));` - which causes my index.html page not to show, but I get a response in terminal

Answer (score 0):

When you open your site (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8090) it sends a GET request but doesn't send back to the browser any response. That is why it seems GET request wasn't made. Send a response in the app.get and it'll send a response.

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res){
  console.log(req);
  res.send('Hello World');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

express.static('client') suggest from where your static files are to be loaded. Here 'client' is treated as your root path.

If your 'client' directory has some 'abcd.img' file then,  http://127.0.0.1:8090/abcd.img will load 'abcd.img'. 'index.html' in your 'client' directory will be loaded by default when you point to root path. That means 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/' will load your index.html file.

Express has a very good documentation on this part. I am pasting it for your reference.
[Express documentation for serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)